# Facing issue com.stripe.exception.ApiConnectionException: IOException during API request to Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

Facing issue com.stripe.exception.ApiConnectionException: IOException during API request to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com): connect timed out Please check your internet connection and try again.  this issue while connecting to stripe from java backend api , any help would be appreciated

Some results says there is change in payment_method_type param , but i am facing issue even in stripe create customer api

Comment: I suggest running https://github.com/stripe/stripe-reachability as a first step to figure out where the connectivity issue is. It could be a temporary network issue or some kind of misconfiguration on your server.